# indexing big collection for faster retrieval of data

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a collection of items with over 10 million records. The records are indexes like this (feel free to criticize if incorrect):

```
        cars.create_index([('car_id',1),('timestamp',-1)], unique=True) 
        cars.create_index([('car_id',1),('timestamp',1)])
        cars.create_index([('timestamp',-1),('car_id',1)])
        cars.create_index([('timestamp',1),('car_id',1)])
        cars.create_index([('timestamp',1)])
        cars.create_index([('timestamp',-1)])
        cars.create_index([('car_id',1)])
```

My objective is to have fast retrieval of cars and their last timestamp (from this document I get some important values). A unique entry is given by the car_id and its timestamp.

**Problem**: Consider the following query: **Get all unique cars (there are ~2000) with their latest timestamp.** Intuitively, since the cars and their timestamp is indexed I would expect a very fast retrieval however - it takes over 65 seconds (on a 4 core cpu + 32gb ram) to get the data.

**Question**: How can I improve the indexing so the retrieval will be much faster?

To be precise, [this is my query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNTruzY77w-) that I'm running but it is still close to the initial request (the query is asking for car_id with the last 2 records).

Comment: To start with you can refer [Compound Index - Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes).

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for the pointer. Correct me if Im wrong, but isnt what I have in the first line of code (in my post) indicates that I'm using a compound index? (car_id + timestamp -1). Thanks

Comment: Yes, its a compound index. For example, the last index uses the prefix of the first two indexes. Also, see this topic [Create Indexes to support your queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/).

Comment: @prasad_ so if I did this properly, what exactly are you pointing here? I'm just not following your comment of how this can solve my challenge. Thanks again

Comment: In summary, you don't need so many indexes (its lot of hard drive space, RAM/memory, and inefficient writes/updates). The provided documentation links in my earlier comments point so.

Comment: @prasad_ ok got it. I'll revise.

Answer (score 2):

In deed having all these indexes is mainly a waste of disk space. In your query you select **all** documents from the collection, so an index will not improve anything. Fetching 10 Million records simply takes some time. An index only helps you to find specific documents. As a rule of thump you can say: If your query selects more than 10% of all data, then a full collection (or in relational databases "full table") scan is usually faster.

However, based on [Optimization to Return the First Document of Each Group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group) try this one:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ car_id: 1, timestamp: -1 })

db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: { car_id: 1, timestamp: -1 } }
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$car_id",
      k_value: { $first: "$k_value" },
      timestamp: { $first: "$timestamp" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added the sorting and surprisingly it takes longer time for the query to execute (extra 15-20 seconds).  Also, note that I added: allowDiskUse=True. Any ideas? Also, based on your answer I have revised my indexing. Using only line 1 and 3 to save space.

Comment: As I said, you select the entire collection, so there is not much you can do. With a shared cluster you could distribute the load over several machines.